# Sitecore versioned image not loading correctly when using language switcher

Tags: image, svg, sitecore, media

I'm running Sitecore 10.3 and have a data template with an image field and an item that's based on that template. The site has two languages.

When using a versioned image in the EN and th-TH versions then publish the site and switch the language in the site everything changes in the page except for the image. Only after hard reload, image updates.

I have noticed that there is no language query string appended in the media url. Any idea why this happens and what could fix this?

Below is the code used for rendering Logo image (.svg):
@Html.Sitecore().BeginField(Model.LogoUrlField, Model.InnerItem, new { haschildren = true, @class =    "logo", @title = Model.LogoTitle })
@Html.Sitecore().Field(Model.LogoImageField, Model.InnerItem)
@Html.Sitecore().EndField()

Answer (score 1):

Setting languageEmbedding to always fixed the issue for me.

```
   <links>
    <urlBuilder>
        <languageEmbedding>always</languageEmbedding>
    </urlBuilder>
   </links>
```

Comment: After all the different things I tried.... this actually did the trick! Thanks